# Deploy HTML5-CSS3-JS-jQuery-Bootstrap UI application in Nginx/Tomcat Server

Tags: html, nginx, tomcat

I am trying to develop a UI application using HTML5-CSS3-JS-jQuery-Bootstrap. Can this UI application be deployed in Nginx/Tomcat Server? If yes, can you please share some links having the deployment steps.

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I researched and it is supported by all web servers.